# spring web controller use as web service

Tags: web-services, spring-mvc, controller

Currently I use Spring mvc to develop my we application. In future there will be a requirement to develop mobile app for this application.

In asp.net c# MVC have ability to use there web controller class as the web service. Then mobile app can use that controller class as web service.

I want to know is there an ability to use Spring MVC controllers as a we service. If yes, then how. Please explain.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily write a Restful webservice using Spring MVC. The controller classes can return XML/JSON as required. It is simply a case of configuring an appropriate `ViewResolver` in this case a `ContentNegotiationViewResolver`.

[This](http://java-diaries.blogspot.com/2011/02/restful-webservices-with-spring.html) is an excellent guide which will walk you through the basics of Spring MVC as a webservice.